# Find a specific word from a list in python

Tags: python

So I have a list like below-

```
list = [scaler-1, scaler-2, scaler-3, backend-1, backend-2, backend-3]
```

I want to create another list from it with the words which starts with 'backend'.How can i do that ?

Please note the content of the list will change from system to system, I want my code to be dynamic, any help?

Comment: here's a hint: there is a built-in `str` method called `startswith`

Comment: do `newlst = [i for i in _list if i.startswith("backend")]`.

Comment: What do you mean by "want my code to be dynamic"? What is dynamic here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, do not use the name `list` for assignment to your objects, you'll shadow the builtin list type.

Then, you can use a *list comprehension* with [`str.startswith`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) in a filter:

```
new_lst = [x for x in lst if x.startswith('backend')]
```