# Find a specific item from a list using python

Tags: python-3.x, list, search

I have a list of 20000 Products with their Description
[This shows the variety of the products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I08Hj.jpg)

I want to be able to write a code that searches a particular word say 'TAPA'
and give a output of all the TAPAs

I found this   [Find a specific word from a list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39996485/find-a-specific-word-from-a-list-in-python) , but it uses `startswith` which finds only the first item for example:

```
 new = [x for x in df1['A'] if x.startswith('00320')]

 ## output ['00320671-01 Guide rail 25N/1660', '00320165S02 - Miniature rolling table']
```

How shall i find for the second letter, third or any other item

P.S- the list consists of strings, integers, floats

Comment: try `[x for x in df1['A'] if '00320' in x]`

Comment: thanks you Akshay it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `string.find(substring)` for this purpose. So in your case this should work:

```
new = [x for x in df1['A'] if x.find('00320') != -1]
```

The `find()` method returns the lowest index of the substring found else returns -1.

To know more about usage of `find()` refer to [Geeksforgeeks.com - Python String | find()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/string-find-python/)

**Edit 1:**
As suggested by @Thierry in comments, a cleaner way to do this is:

```
new = [x for x in df1['A'] if '00320' in x]
```

Comment: `if x.find('00320') != -1` can be more simply and efficiently written as `if '00320' in x:`

Comment: Indeed. Updated the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot you guys. Is there a way to find similar items ? like every item that looks like '00320047S01' or '00201179S01' ??

Comment: @AdarshBhansali try regex if you have fixed pattern

Comment: there is a pattern but i do not know how to to use regex

Comment: You'll need Python's `re` module for this. Its easy to implement for simple patterns. You could use [Python's Official Doc on Re](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html) and Google's [Python Regular Expressions](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/regular-expressions) to get started with regex in Python.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in functions of Pandas to [find partial string matches](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) and [generate lists](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.tolist.html):

```
new = df1['A'][df1['A'].astype(str).str.contains('00320')]['A'].tolist()
```

An advantage of pandas str.contains() is that the use of regex is possible.

Comment: Thanks man much obliged. Is there a way to find similar items ? like every item that looks like '00320047S01' or '00201179S01' ??

Comment: Welcome. Similar items is a classic regex case - if you haven't used regex yet, check it out! You could find '00320047S01' or '00201179S01'  by using ...str.contains(r'00[0-9]{6}S01',regex=True)... - in words: find any items that has '00' followed by 6 numbers ([0-9] = only match numbers, {6} = exactly six times) followed by 'S01'.  Read here for an intro: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions